# Will "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan" affect network traffic?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, pci-bus

I am trying to remove and rescan a set of pci network cards using :

```
$echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/pci-id/remove

$echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

As I see `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan` to be trigged for all pci devices will it affect the network traffic on network cards which I am not removing ??

Thanks,

Comment: It is implemented in http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/source/drivers/pci/pci-sysfs.c#L306.  [`pci_rescan_bus` is documented as](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/source/drivers/pci/probe.c#L2497) "Scan a PCI bus and child buses for new devices, adds them, and enables them." And https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci says "Writing a non-zero value to this attribute will force a rescan of all PCI buses in the system, and re-discover previously removed devices.". I think rescan for removed cards will have little or no effect on non-removed cards.

Comment: Is there a solution for this question ? I wanted to ask the same question

Comment: @ransh I used it as stated above and it works fine without affecting other pci cards.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, maybe you can write it as a solution for this question.

Comment: @ransh not sure if its the answer. The only thing is it works without any issue.

Comment: making the same pci rescan hangs linux for me